# jQuery DataTables: Use button to filter rows on all pages?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datatables

I'm using jQuery DataTables to format a table, and I want to create a button that filters rows *on all pages*. Currently the filter (which toggles visibility of rows containing text with the color #bfbfff) only applies to the currently visible page.

I know that I'd have to use the [DataTables API](http://datatables.net/manual/plug-ins/search) to make this work, I just don't know how to integrate my existing jQuery into the API.

```
$("a#notes").on("click", function() {
    $("#example tbody tr").toggle();
    $("#example tbody tr td span[style='color:#bfbfff;']").closest("tr").toggle();
} );
```

[Fiddle showing filter only applying to current page](http://jsfiddle.net/emturano/Ls0hbtd6/5/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the latest DataTables API:

```
var _fieldNotesFilter = false;

$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push( function ( settings, searchData, index, rowData, counter ) {
    if ( settings.nTable.id !== 'example' ) {
        return true;
    }

    if ( ! _fieldNotesFilter ) {
        return true;
    }
    else if ( rowData.item.match(/rgb\(191, 191, 255/) || rowData.item.match(/#bfbfff/) ) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
} );


$(document).ready( function () {
    $('#filter_notes').on( 'click', function () {
        //Invert the filtering flag
        _fieldNotesFilter = ! _fieldNotesFilter;

        // Redraw the table to update the filtering change
        $('#example').DataTable().draw();
    } );
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

You could include your own filter in order to make it work to the whole data (all pages). Read more about filtering in datatables [here](http://datatables.net/development/filtering).

The working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k1orkxa1/) using your example.

The javascript must be something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var oTable = $('#example').dataTable();

    $("a#notes").on("click", function() {
        oTable.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push( 
             function( oSettings, aData, iDataIndex ) { 
             var tr = oTable.fnGetNodes(iDataIndex);
             var result=$(tr).find("td span[style='color:#bfbfff;']");    
             return result.length;
        });
        oTable.fnDraw();
    });     

});
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, and while it works, it contains the outdated DataTables API. I've submitted an answer with the latest API, and a bit different logic.